# Updating Disqus SSO config on the fly?

Tags: angularjs, disqus

My site is a single page ajax site.
So when I login there is no postback to the server.

In order to become logged on with Disqus I should use this code:

```
    var disqus_config = function () {
        // The generated payload which authenticates users with Disqus
        this.page.remote_auth_s3 = "generated payload";
        this.page.api_key = "mypublic key";

        // This adds the custom login/logout functionality
        this.sso = {
            ... urls and such ..
        };
    };
```

I can generate the SSO payload in my login service and pass it to the client.
But how do I notify Disqus that there now is a payload that should be activated?
The above script executed when the page loaded, long before the login code.

Ideas?

Comment: Can you point me to a resource of how `"generated payload"` is being generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `DISQUS.reset` function to reload the Disqus embed, and update specific elements of the config, in your case the new SSO payload once the user is logged-in:

```
var disqus_sso_payload_update = function() {
  this.page.remote_auth_s3 = "new payload";
}

DISQUS.reset({reload:true,
              config:disqus_sso_payload_update});
```

The `reset` function is documented for [its use in AJAX page changes](http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/472107-using-disqus-on-ajax-sites) - but from my reading of the source code, it will apply any change you provide to the existing config.